# How magento creates local.xml?

Tags: magento-1.7

How Magento creates app/etc/local.xml? 
Where should I look into to get the procedure of this local.xml creation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The local.xml file is created in the file app/code/core/Mage/Install/Model/Installer/Config.php

The creation of the file is trigger by the `Mage_Install_WizardController` in the function `configPostAction()` that calls the `Mage_Install_Model_Installer::installConfig()` function and this then calls the `Mage_Install_Model_Installer_Config::install()` function that writes to the local.xml file.